# How can I define an Entity column so that it has a default value on creation but can be overwritten via Entity Framwork?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my `Users` table, I have a column named `CreatedOn` which has a "Default Value or Binding" set to `(getdate())`. In my .edmx file for this model, I define this column as `<Property Name="CreatedOn" Type="datetime2" Precision="7" Nullable="false" StoreGeneratedPattern="Computed"/>`.

- Advantage: the field is set as a current timestamp upon creation
- Disadvantage: I can't change the field via Entity Framework

I can, however, change the field definition in the .edmx file to `StoreGeneratedPattern="None"` which gives me:

- Advantage: I can change the field any time after creation via Entity Framework
- Disadvantage: the field is not set as a current timestamp upon creation

The problem is that Entity Framework,  when I specify `StoredGeneratedPattern="None"` for this column in the .edmx file, instead of letting the Database set the GETTIME() by itself, sends a value `0001-01-01 00:00:00` which then overwrites the database default. I know this from logging the SQL statement that Entity sends: `INSERT [dbo].[Users]([LoginName], [Password], ..., [CreatedOn]) VALUES (@0, @1, ..., @7) where @7 = '0001-01-01 00:00:00' (Type = DateTime2)`.

**What do I have to do so that I get this:**

- **Advantage: the field is set as a current timestamp upon creation**
- **Advantage: I can change the value of this field any time after creation via Entity Framework**

Comment: timestamp column are not created to be modified by user. Only by EF. So why not creating a new column RowVersion and use it as timestamp like it done more commonly?

Comment: You are generally right, but in this case, I am writing an import module which in some cases has to import numerous user records that have the same e-mail, at which point I have to determine which is most recent, and overwrite the current database record with the most recent `CreatedOn` value.

Comment: Have you considered setting the default value in a parameter-less constructor? The issue is that it will be the class creation date, not the record's, but depending on your goals, might be an option

Answer (score 0):

You could use your second approach and mitigate the disadvantage by setting `CreatedOn` to `DateTime.Now` before saving in your app code. So the `CreatedOn` prop is fully managed by app code in the app but if a `User` is created directly in the DB the default constraint will kick in.

Here are a few way to approach setting `CreatedOn` that could be used depending on the situation:

1. Set it before saving like you'd set any other property.
2. As ESG mentioned in the comments, set it in a parameter-less constructor.
3. If you're using an abstraction layer on top of EF like the repository pattern, you could create an abstract base class or interface that contains the `CreatedOn` property and inherit/implement in any classes you want to add that prop to. Then create a base repository save method that checks if the objects being saved are of the type that have the `CreatedOn` property and, if so, set it before saving.